# Handling Mojave permissions ( camera, mic & accessibility) for two instances of app in same machine

Tags: macos-mojave

**My Use case** : 
I have an automation framework for Mac that launches 2 instances of the same app ( same bundle id) available at different locations to simulate two endpoint cases for media calls. With introduction of Mojave permissions, when I grant permission( camera , mic & accessibility) for one instance of the app, the other instance doesn't have the same permissions.

Since the bundle id is same, is it not that providing permission for the app is carried over to both instances?

I tried pushing a system profile to provide permissions but that doesn't seem to work

Also added an apple script to continuously check for permission pop-up and click ok to it. This works for mic and camera but not for accessibility. Also when each instance is launched the permission would be asked again.

1. Is there a way to by default provide all access to the application by default without asking for any permission pop-ups?
2. Or is there any way to tweak something at the OS level to not ask for permissions at all ( behave same as <10.14) .. I tried disabling system integrity but that doesn't seems solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to code-sign all versions/copies of the app using the same identity.

When an app is not code-signed and the system needs to record its identity (as for permissions), it generates an ad hoc code signature. That signature, though, only matches that exact build of the app. Another copy of the app that is different in any code-signature-relevant way is not considered to have the same identity. In fact, it's likely to be considered "malicious" as it appears to have been tampered with.

If you code-sign your app with appropriate designated requirements, that enables the system to understand that two different versions of an app have the same identity and should share permissions. This is key to an app maintaining permissions through an upgrade to a new version, for example.

Comment: Thanks @ken. This is really helpful. Since the second version of the app was a debug build it wasn't code signed earlier. I did code sign now and things seems to be fine. Thanks again